# Customize Jekyll remote theme for GitHub Pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm new to using Jekyll theme for GitHub page. I was able to successfully customize a local theme following [Customizing your Jekyll theme's CSS](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/#customizing-your-jekyll-themes-css) but I couldn't find any documentation about what to do if the theme is remote.

Here is what I tried. First, I started with a clean GitHub page and followed step 4 in [Adding a Jekyll theme in your site's _config.yml file](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site/#adding-a-jekyll-theme-in-your-sites-_configyml-file) to opt-in [my theme](https://github.com/chuanqisun/primer) that's forked from GitHub's default theme

_config.yml:

```
     github: [metadata]
     encoding: UTF-8
     kramdown:
         input: GFM
         hard_wrap: false
     future: true
     jailed: false
-     theme: jekyll-theme-primer
+     remote_theme: chuanqisun/primer
     gfm_quirks: paragraph_end
```

At this point, everything just works out-of-the-box. But when I add

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";
```

in /assets/css/style.scss, GitHub Page complaints that site.theme doesn't exist.
[image]
So I also tried

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.remote_theme }}";
```

but the import still failed.
[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to customize a remote theme? I know that I can just make customization in my forked repository but some customization are specific to one site and I want to store that in my site's repo. This way I can share the theme with multiple sites without enforcing one site's customization to the rest of the sites. Thanks!

Comment: what is the name of the file you're trying to import here..?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understood the build process. I believe I'm trying to import the [style.scss in the remote repo](https://github.com/chuanqisun/primer/blob/master/assets/css/style.scss)

Comment: Aha! thanks for the pointer, I think I might have understood the problem. {{site.theme}} is just "jekyll-theme-primer". It might work if I explicitly say @import "jekyll-theme-primer"! I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone in a similar situation, here is what worked for me, using the [Minimal mistakes](https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes) theme as a remote theme.

It has no `assets/css/style.scss`, but an `assets/css/main.scss` that then imports all the partial files under `_sass`. Trying to import main or empty brackets as the official docs suggest, **doesn't work**. The way to go is to copy the main theme's file and then customize it.

So in this case I created a local copy of `assets/css/main.scss` and appended the desired css changes. That was enough. If a theme doesn't have one central file tying everything together, you might need to copy more files, but that's it.